# Color Literal not being suggested - Xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4, xcode9, uicolor

Im trying to set an attribute with a specific color, in this case I want to use the Color Literal function however Xcode is not suggesting Color Literal and only giving me the options to pick from UIColor... How can I fix the suggestions issue?

[image: Color Literal not being suggested]

[image: Second Attempt with typing "L" after "Color"]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possibly because the compiler does not know that you want a color. You are putting it into a dictionary and all you have told it is that it is of type `Any`.

Try creating the color first...

```
let color: UIColor = ColorLiteral
```

That should then pop up the picker. And you can put `color` into your dictionary.

Comment: So the reason why I didn't think I had to create the color first was bc '.strokeColor' is a property that took in a UIColor so I figured swift would know? But your suggestion worked! Ty

Comment: @GermanFlores ah, yeah, your dictionary is just a collection of strings and types. So even though you know that a particular string relates to a color the compiler just sees it as another string.

Answer (score 7):

I think you can add this literal to your code snippet library.

```
#colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
```